# After enable setUseWideViewPort(true) content not scaling below some value?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webkit

i am working with android webview and here to avoid content wrap i am enabling -

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

and after setting this i am getting some factor to fit the page in device and trying to set this using-

```
webview.setInitialScale(18);
```

But it is not scale the page as 18 so please tell me how to set the scale of page to fit it properly in device.Actually here `wideViewPort` is enabled as true so the small value are not being set to `webview` but if i disable `WideViewPort` content wrap so please suggest me solutions??

Comment: Please tell me i have to enable the wide view port because after enabling this on zooming + or - the content do not wraps so please tell me the way i should use??

Comment: Here i checked one thing untill horizontal scrollbar is there you can set the value but whenever there is no horizontal scroll bar after that you can not set the setinitialscale(some_small_value)